# Creating Batch file to go through text files and delete all quotation marks

Tags: batch-file, text-files

i am trying to write a batch file which goes through all text files in one Folder and deletes the quotation marks in every text file but also overwrites them so they still have the same filenames.

I have already written a batch file which does this with one specific Textfile which is called limits.txt and then it saves the same Textfile without the quotation marks in limits_new.txt:

```
@echo off
if not exist "limits.txt" goto :EOF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del "limits_new.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("limits.txt") do (
set "Line=%%I"
set "Line=!Line:"= !" 
echo !Line!>>"limits_new.txt"
)
del "limits.txt"
endlocal
```

So how can i change this to go through more Textfiles like limits1.txt 
test.txt
and overwrite them without the qutation marks.?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You do know that you're not deleting the doublequotes, don't you? You're replacing each one of them with a space.

Comment: yes sorry i forget to explain this thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use another `for`, and substitute the filename throughout with the variable you're using for that:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    del "%%f.new" 2>nul
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%%f") do (
        set "Line=%%I"
        set "Line=!Line:"= !" 
        echo !Line!>>"%%f.new"
    )
    del "%%f"
    ren "%%f.new" "%%f"
    endlocal
)
```

This will generate limits.txt.new from limits.txt and then replace the original limits.txt with the new version. If you want to keep the limits_new.txt naming convention then I think you want `%%~nf_new.txt` as the output filename and drop the `ren`.

Note that if you have `sed`, e.g. from Git Bash, you can do an in-place file edit with a regular expression:

```
sed -i -e "s/\"/ /g" limits.txt
```

and Git Bash has a similar `for` you can use to update all files, e.g.

```
for _f in *.txt; do sed -i -e 's/"/ /g' $_f; done
```

but beware: depending on where you got your sed from this might also switch all of the line endings from CRLF to just LF.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!